# django how to change time format to naturally in a queryset or serializer

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

This is the model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    """

    评论表

    """
    nid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    news = models.ForeignKey(verbose_name='评论文章', to='News',to_field='id',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(verbose_name='评论者', to='User',to_field='id',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.CharField(verbose_name='评论内容', max_length=255)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='创建时间', auto_now_add=True)
    parent_comment = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
```

This is the view:

```
def get_comment_tree(request):
        news_id = request.GET.get("news_id")
        ret = list(Comment.objects.filter(news_id=news_id).values("nid", "content", "parent_comment_id",'create_time',username=F('user__username')))
        return JsonResponse(ret, safe=False)
```

My question is ,how to convert the create_time to human time like "5 minute ago" in django?

Comment: Would it be fine to convert in the template?

Comment: This does *not* belong in a `QuerySet`. This belongs in a serializer...

Comment: Thank you for your reply,this is will display by ajax not by template loop.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thank you for reply,yes you are right,do you have anyway that can convert the time in it?

Comment: @William why not do this at the client side? That way you know both the exact date time and the humanized version at the client side. If you send it after serializing it you would lose this benefit at the client side.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you are right,the reason is I'm trying to build a comment tree by ajax.